# how to change background on mouse hover?

Tags: html, hover, layer

i have a div that contains an image fills all the div,
positioned on it a text.
when the mouse is over the container div the mouse will change to pointer(no problem),but and the image changed to look like pressed one.
But this wont happened thus the text represents other layer.
so could any one help me to resolve this problem in html and css?

```
<div style="float: right; width: 127px; height: 35px; background-color: rgba(139, 84, 164,.44); background-color: rgb(229, 230, 218); 
                    cursor:pointer; position:absolute;">

                    <div style="overflow: hidden; width: 87px;  height: 100%; float: right; position:absolute; z-index:2; background-color:#FF0099;
                                margin-left: 40px;">
                        <p class="para" style="color: rgb(0,178,192);  padding-top: 8px; padding-right: 5px;">اسم الملف</p>
                    </div>


                    <div style="position:absolute; z-index:1; ">
                        <img src="saba/playa.png" onMouseOver="this.src='saba/playao.png'" onMouseOut="this.src='saba/playa.png'"style="float: left;">
                    </div>

            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand well..

But I think this shows what you want to create...

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="text-div">
        some text
    </div>
    <div class="colored-button-on-hover"></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.wrapper {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #999;
    position: relative;
}

.wrapper .text-div {
    float: right;
    color: #000;
}

.wrapper .colored-button-on-hover {
    float: left;
    width: 30px;
    height: 25px;
    background: red;
}

/*on wrapper div hovered*/
.wrapper:hover {
    background: blue;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.wrapper:hover .text-div {
    color: #FFF;
}

.wrapper:hover .colored-button-on-hover {
    background: yellow;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

Here is jsfiddle sample: http://jsfiddle.net/AYjmF/